# JSF get current values from bean

Tags: jsf, model-view-controller, jdbc, primefaces

Hi everyone thanks for helping.
I need to get current values from bean back to jsf.

**JSF (example)**

```
<!-- InputText USERNAME  -->
        <h:outputText style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;" value="Username"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText a:placeholder="Enter user.." id="username" value="#{regBean.username}" required="true"></h:inputText>
        <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
<!-- COMMANDBUTTON SEND -->
        <p:commandButton update=":dialogConf" style="font-size:10px;width:68px;height:32px;margin-left:70px;" type="submit" value="Sign Up" icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-e"  styleClass="botonesR"
        onerror="PF('errorDlg').show();" oncomplete="PF('confirmation').show();PF('registration').hide();"
        action="#{regBean.doActionReg}" ajax="true">
        </p:commandButton>
```

**Bean (example)**

```
public void insertNewUser(){

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pStatement = null;
    String user = this.getUsername();
    String SQL = "INSERT INTO USER"
            + "(USERNAME)VALUES"
            + "(?)";
    try {
        conn = getdbConnection();
        pStatement = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
        pStatement.setString(1, user);
        //Execute insertSQL
        pStatement.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("User:" + user);
        System.out.println("Record is inserted into USUARIOS table");

    }catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        try{
            if (pStatement!=null){
                pStatement.close();
            }
            if (conn!=null){
                conn.close();
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

until here everything works fine records are being saved properly.
Now I want to see the current user in confirmation dialog after insert query

**Same JSF**

```
  <p:dialog header="Confirmation" showEffect="explode" id="dialogConf" widgetVar="confirmation" hideEffect="explode" height="125px" width="378px" modal="true" resizable="false">
    <h:outputText value="User ( #{regBean.username}) is now in our db"></h:outputText>
 </p:dialog>
```

here #{regBean.username} doesn't show me the current value of username.

Comment: Where do you call insertNewUser and where do you show and update the dialog? See [ask] and create an mcve

Comment: I just updated my answer sorry my apologices

Comment: It still is not an mcve. Relevant calls missing, new calls show up, not minimal etc… try without a database first… start simple

Comment: Well... what'd be the difference without a db ? everything works fine I just need to update the value of the bean in xhtml file when I save the record that's it, I got the value of the last record inserted instead of the current record

Comment: Maybe I can't do that how I was thinking so no worries I'll find another way thanks for helping anyways

Comment: If i set the value of db last record inserted instead of bean it could be a solution

Comment: No idea… be lots of things. Hence the question for an mcve

Comment: As the question is stated, I could bet in the dialog not being updated before being shown. The dialog values are evaluated for the client when the server sends the response. In that moment its value is null or empty. You'll have to update it when user changes the input, using ajax calls.

Comment: thanks I'll find out how to use ajax with jsf I'm not sure how it works in jsf.

Comment: Okay fixed was pretty simple infact just adding update, Sorry was a really noob question thanks for helping guys

Answer (score 0):

Solved just adding update properly

```
<!-- COMMANDBUTTON SEND -->
    <p:commandButton update="userReg" style="font-size:10px;width:68px;height:32px;margin-left:70px;" type="submit" value="Sign Up" icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-e"  styleClass="botonesR"
    onerror="PF('errorDlg').show();" oncomplete="PF('confirmation').show();PF('registration').hide();"
    action="#{regBean.doActionReg}">
    </p:commandButton>
```

where I show results

```
  <p:dialog header="Confirmation" showEffect="explode" id="dialogConf" widgetVar="confirmation" hideEffect="explode" height="125px" width="378px" modal="true" resizable="false">
<h:outputText id="userReg" value="User ( #{regBean.username}) is now in our db"></h:outputText>
```